# How a controller hits from a browser even it is a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class, asp.net-mvc-4

I am beginner to MVC, today I was working on creating a simple application using MVC by following [intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) tutorial. then I checked and didn't get how a Controller is being hitting from web browser directly even it is class. May be I could be wrong or due to lack of knowledge I don't know the scene that is working behind it. Can experts please explain what is the reason why it happens so.

any idea??

**UPDATED ::**

I found

> A Controller is a class which performs the linkage between the View and the Model

from [ASP-NET-MVC-for-Beginners-in-Web-Development](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/765519/ASP-NET-MVC-for-Beginners-in-Web-Development).

Answer (score 1):

In few words, when a client requests a page, sends an http request to the server. Then the server that receives this request through some checking finds that the requested url is for an application that is an mvc app and some modules that reside in IIS handle this an make an instance of the controller class and call the corresponding method.

More formally,

> Requests to an ASP.NET MVC-based Web application first pass through
>   the UrlRoutingModule object, which is an HTTP module. This module
>   parses the request and performs route selection. The UrlRoutingModule
>   object selects the first route object that matches the current
>   request. (A route object is a class that implements RouteBase, and is
>   typically an instance of the Route class.) If no routes match, the
>   UrlRoutingModule object does nothing and lets the request fall back to
>   the regular ASP.NET or IIS request processing. From the selected Route
>   object, the UrlRoutingModule object obtains an object that implements
>   the IRouteHandler interface and that is associated with the Route
>   object. Typically, in an MVC application, this will be an instance of
>   the MvcRouteHandler class. The MvcRouteHandler instance creates an
>   MvcHandler object that implements the IHttpHandler interface. The
>   MvcHandler object then selects the controller that will ultimately
>   handle the request. For more information, see ASP.NET Routing.

as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612(v=vs.100).aspx).

A good picture I found [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/LYHK270114-Detailed-ASP.NET-MVC-Pipeline.html) that depicts the above is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because ASP.NET MVC handler instantiates the `Controller` (depending upon the route configuration) using Reflection. Once instantiated, the handler calls the `Action` method with parameters(If Any).

Its all done using .NET Reflection.

You can see the gory details [Here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/LYHK270114-Detailed-ASP.NET-MVC-Pipeline.html)

See how to create a basic version of the MVC(toy version) [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/13852/create-your-own-Asp-Net-mvc-framework-from-scratch-in-15-min.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first review how routing works. That is where everything starts.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Ultimately, the ASP.NET MVC framework decides which controller/view to dispatch to base on:

1. Routing config (found in global.asax.cs in older MVC or in App_Start\RouteConfig.cs in newer). These are the rules for the routing engine.
2. Convention - Within the "rules of convention" from (1), when a URL matches a rule, the engine dispatches it to the class & method. Example: /Foo/Bar/42 maps to FooController.Bar(Id : 42) action method by a pattern. Note below the 3 variables within the pattern (controller, action and id).

   ```
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```

That mapping is achieved dynamically by runtime reflection.